# Kibana Dashboard Throws Internal Server Error 500 After Few Days of Deployment

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, http-status-code-500, apm

I have deployed a Kibana service with Elasticsearch and APM server containers. After a few days of deployment, I encountered an internal server error (status code 500) when trying to access the Kibana dashboard.

Restarting the Elasticsearch, Kibana, and APM server containers temporarily resolved the issue, but it recurred after some time.

I'm seeking insights into the potential causes of this issue and possible solutions. Could it be related to the volume of data logged into Elasticsearch? How can I troubleshoot and resolve this recurring internal server error in my Kibana service?

Any guidance or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!